# why glutPostRedisplay has a delay

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I'm new to openGL.I wonder why in function Mutate GetPixelDifference() is always called before glutPostRedisplay().And how can I fix it.

```
import sys
import time
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *


def GetPixelDifference():
    print("calculate")


def Draw():
    print("draw")
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.4)
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL)
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
    glVertex2f(1,1)
    glVertex2f(-1,1)
    glVertex2f(0,0)
    glEnd()
    glFlush()
    GetPixelDifference()


def Mutate():
    print("mutate")
    glutPostRedisplay()  
    #time.sleep(5)
    print("=======")
    print("=wrong=")
    print("=======")
    GetPixelDifference() 


glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(300, 300)
glutCreateWindow(b"My clock")
glutDisplayFunc(Draw)
print("main")
glutIdleFunc(Mutate)
glutMainLoop()

'''   
And this is what i get

main
draw
calculate
mutate
=======
=wrong=
=======
calculate
draw
calculate
draw
'''
```

calculate is called before draw.But I want call calculate when drawing is finished,cause this calculate is for all the pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glutPostRedisplay merely sets a flag, that in the *next* iteration of the *event loop* as the final operation the display callback shall be called. I.e. it doesn't take immediate action.

This is the documented behavior, see: https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node20.html